# Create dynamic images from WPF User Control inside an HTTP Handler

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, xaml, httphandler, pivotviewer

I'm using Microsoft's PivotViewer control in one of my Silverlight projects.  I'm creating a JIT collection and was hoping to dynamically generate the images based on the rendered result of a WPF UserControl.  In order to generate the images I'm using an HTTP Handler to serve the images up dynamically.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how I might best go about this.  It's all quite a mashup of technologies and a bit difficult to know where best to begin.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I have found a guy that's done this in ASP.Net MVC [here](http://amazedsaint.blogspot.com/2010/07/xaml-meets-aspnet-mvc-create-databound.html) -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stream on the HTTP stream a WPF visual, the pseudo code would be something like this:

```
        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render([your WPF visual or control instance]);

        // choose the format if you want something other than png
        PngBitmapEncoder png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));

        // stream this on the web
        png.Save([the web stream, like Response.OutputStream]);
```

Comment: Done this but I'm getting nothing but a black rectangle,..no matter what xaml I give it.  Any idea?

Comment: Ahh,..found it.  You have to call Control.Arrange() before it will display properly.